# Extent Report: Name of output file does not change even when defined

Tags: selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Im not able to change the name of the outputfile from the extent reports. It does always create the report file called `index.html`.

In my code, i want to display the `name + date/time.html`

Here is the codeline for the path definition:

```
        private const string ExtentReportPath = @".\ExtentReports\";
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void ExtentStart()
        {
            ExtentHtmlReporter htmlreporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(ExtentReportPath + "UnlockInstruction_Test" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss") + ".html");
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.AttachReporter(htmlreporter);
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void ExtentClose()
        {
            extent.Flush();
        }
```

**First solution ive found is:**

I changed `ExtentHtmlReporter` to `ExtentV3HtmlReporter`.

But after using `ExtentV3HtmlReporter`, VS is displaying a warning which says, that this method is obsolete and wont be supported in the future.. so still waiting for a up to date solution.

Comment: Any solution for this

Comment: Sorry no. I dont use Extent Report anymore. The only solution was the one mentioned above.

Comment: What are you using now? Can you share

Comment: Im not using any report tool/nuget package anymore.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read the static name (index) is expected behavior to increase the efficiency of reporting.
You can add a unique name to the folder name instead of the file, so you would create sub-folders for each index file like this:

```
String path =System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//reports//"+time+"//index.html";
ExtentSparkReporter reporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(path);
```